# Set RTSP/UDP buffer size in FFmpeg/LibAV

Tags: ffmpeg, udp, rtsp, buffer-overflow, libav

***Note***: I'm aware ffmpeg and libav are [different libraries](https://libav.org/about.html#history). This is a problem common to both.

***Disclaimer***: Duplicate of [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14593531/too-small-ffmpeg-rtsp-decoding-buffer) marked as answered but actually didn't give a proper solution.

---

Insufficient UDP buffer size causes broken streams for several high resolution video streams. In LibAV/FFMPEG it's possible to set the udp buffer size for udp urls (udp://...) by appending some [options (buffer_size)](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#udp) to it.

However, for RTSP urls this is [not supported](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#rtsp).

These are the only solutions I've found:

- Rebuilding ffmpeg/libav changing the UDP_MAX_PKT_SIZE in the [udp.c](https://libav.org/doxygen/release/0.8/udp_8c_source.html) source file.
- Using a [nasty hack](https://lists.libav.org/pipermail/libav-api/2015-January/000962.html) to find and modify the required value, by casting some private structs.
- Using a different decoding library (proposed solution to aforementioned related SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14593531/too-small-ffmpeg-rtsp-decoding-buffer)).

None of these is actually a solution. From what I found it should be possible to use the API's [`AVOptions`](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.2/group__avoptions.html) to find and set this value. Or else, the [AVDictionary](https://libav.org/doxygen/master/group__lavu__dict.html).

It's very difficult to find how to set these throughout the documentation of either libav or ffmpeg.

**Update:**

The following patches have been submited to Libav tackling this topic, thanks to Libav developer *@lu_zero* :

- [Add a buffer_size option](https://patches.libav.org/patch/57165/)
- [Map the urloptions to AVOptions](https://patches.libav.org/patch/57163/)

Which should offer a hint on how to implement those, still these are not yet available through the official stable API.

Comment: You could increase the default OS UDP buffer limits I guess. [Improving UDP Peformance](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Web_Platform/5/html/Administration_And_Configuration_Guide/jgroups-perf-udpbuffer.html)

Comment: Not available for Windows, it may work for other platforms.. but still this should be set through the API.

Comment: For Windows see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18985816/change-default-socket-buffer-size-under-windows)

Comment: Thanks. However I don't want to solve it for windows only. Moreover I know that it should be possible to do so within my application only. It's just that the API is not clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since [this](https://git.libav.org/?p=libav.git;a=commit;h=e3ec6fe7bb2a622a863e3912181717a659eb1bad) commit it is enough to pass `buffer_size` as option and it gets forwarded to the `udp` protocol through the `rtp` protocol.

I tested and it works as intended.

Comment: What about TCP?

Comment: The commit link is broken

Answer (score 7):

FYI, the latest ffmpeg2.8.5 already has this option.
I use it to set the the buffer_size

```
av_dict_set(&options, "buffer_size", "655360", 0);
```

and I got this output:

[udp @ 0xb4945090] attempted to set receive buffer to size 655360 but it only ended up set as 327680
After some searching I run

```
echo 2097152 > /proc/sys/net/core/rmem_max
```

to fix the warning